# Printing out form submission

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I want to print out a form that has been filled by the user. But when the print button is pressed, only the default values for the inputs get printed out. Im using angular. Does anybody know how to print out the filled form with out having to append every input field (I have many) to the docToPrint.document.write?

```
$rootScope.printDiv = function(divName) {
                var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
                var docToPrint = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=700,height=400');
                docToPrint.document.open();
                docToPrint.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</html>');
                docToPrint.document.close();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know whether this will meet your requirement or not but i had this piece

```
 ng-click="window.print();"
```

this opens the print screen with all the view,from there you can print it

Answer (score 0):

In angular we have the concept of $scope which lies between controller and view. So what you can do, can make one form model in controller and set some default values with every field.
Now you make one form and bind that model with it. So every field will be populated with some default value which you had given in controller. Now when you will press the Print button then model will have all the updated values and rest will be the default values.

Example is attached below:

### Controller

```
angular.module('mainModule', [])
.conroller('formCntrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.model = {
      name: 'Dummy Name',  // these are some default values
      age: 20,
      address: 'XyZ',
      profession: 'Abc'
   };

   $scope.submitForm = function() {
      /* here you can play with $scope.model which will have all updated values and if any field is not touched then it will have default value for it which is given above  */
   };

});
```

### html

```
<html>
<body ng-app="mainModule">
   <div ng-controller="formCntrl">
   <form name="regForm">
     Name: <input type="text" ng-model="model.name" name="name" /><br>
     Age: <input type="text" ng-model="model.age" name="name" /><br>
     Address: <input type="text" ng-model="model.address" name="name" /><br>
     Profession: <input type="text" ng-model="model.profession" name="name"/><br>
    <input type="button" value="Print" ng-click="submitForm()" />
   <form>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see! But why must you specify it in the controller first? Doesn't ng-model automatically create the variable you assigned it into the scope?

Comment: Yes but how you will configure the default values then? Model is created in the controller so that we can provide some default values for every field. Else you can skip it also.

Answer (score 0):

this will suit your req. https://dzone.com/articles/building-simple-angularjs

```
     myApp.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope,$window) {
         $scope.print=function(){       
         $window.print();
       }
```